# How to get relationaship from SQL query

Tags: mysql, debugging, entity-relationship, normalization

I have normalise database in MySQL. There is not any relationship defined in the database between any two tables. All relationship are virtual.

It is very hard to find the relationship between the tables while debuging the large query.

Is any tool available which can find out the relations between tables from the large query?

Comment: If the relationships aren't defined how could a tool guess what they might be? (What do you mean by "virtual"?)

Comment: By "virtual", I think Ozzone means the relationships are defined in the application code, and do not have `FOREIGN KEY` defined on the tables.

Comment: @Ozzone can you give an example of a query, and what kind of output you want from it? I have a hard time thinking what it is you want.